# Not able to click element after tap in appium 1.7.1 for ios

Tags: appium

Please help to solve this issue in Appium 1.7.1 for Ios.

I am not able to click on that particular element after tap.

I have this below code:

```
TouchAction touch1 = new TouchAction(driver);
touch1.tap (-49,-176).perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use appDriver.findElement(By.).click().

If you still want to use positions, keep in account of margin / padding for the element, if there are any.